# Better way of finding Prime Factors of a number

Tags: c++, math, primes

I'm solving an problem where you're given a number of test cases. For each case, you're given a range(from x to y, inclusive). Within this range I must count all the numbers whose sum of prime factors is exactly K.

for example:

```
5 15 2
```

We know that there 5 numbers which have exactly 2 prime factors (6, 10, 12, 14, and 15).

Now my code works perfectly, but it's too slow. And I was looking for a faster way to generate prime numbers via C++. Here's my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <deque>
#include <queue>

#define Fill(s, v) memset(s, v, sizeof(s))
#define skipChar() (scanf("%c", &useless));
#define scan(x) do{while((x=getchar())<'0'); for(x-='0'; '0'<=(_=getchar());x=(x<<3)+(x<<1)+_-'0');}while(0)
#define rekt return false;
#define notrekt return true;
char _, useless;

using namespace std;
typedef pair <int, int> intpair;
vector<int> primes;

void sieve(int n){
bool *prime = new bool[n +1];
fill(prime, prime + n+1, true);
prime[0] = false;
prime[1] = false;
int m = sqrt(n);
for(int i = 2; i <= m; i++)
    if(prime[i])
        for(int k = i*i; k <= n; k+=i){
            prime[k] = false;
            if(prime[k])primes.push_back(k);
        }
for(int i = 0; i <n; i++){
    if(prime[i])
        primes.push_back(i);
     }
}

int main()
{
int t;
int c = 1;
scan(t);
sieve(1000);
while(t--){
    int a, b, k;
    scan(a);
    scan(b);
    scan(k);
    int realCount = 0;
    for(int i = a; i <= b; i++){
        int count = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < primes.size(); j++){
            if(i % primes[j] == 0){
                    count++;
            }
        }
        if(count == k)realCount++;
    }
    cout << "Case #"<< c << ": "<< realCount <<endl;
    c++;
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

**Thanks to everyone for contribution! Here's Fast and Optimized Code!**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <deque>
#include <queue>

#define F(a, s, val) fill(a, a + s, val);
#define skipChar() (scanf("%c", &useless));
#define scan(x) do{while((x=getchar())<'0'); for(x-='0'; '0'<=_=getchar());x=(x<<3)+(x<<1)+_-'0');}while(0)
#define rekt return false;
#define notrekt return true;
char _, useless;

using namespace std;
typedef pair <int, int> intpair;

int *omega = new int[10000001];

void omg(){
    for(int i = 2; i < 10000000; i++)
            if(omega[i] == 0)
                    for(int j = i; j < 10000001; j+=i)
                            omega[j]++;
}

int main(){
    int t;
    int c = 1;
    F(omega, 10000001, 0);
    omg();
    scan(t);
    while(t--){
        int a, b, k;
        scan(a);
        scan(b);
        scan(k);
        int cc = 0;
        for(int i = a; i <= b; i++)
                    if(omega[i] == k)
                            cc++;
        printf("Case #%i: %i\n", c, cc);
        c++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you want to count all the numbers which has K diffrent prime factor. not sum of prime factors. Right?

Comment: How large can the range get?

Comment: The #defines convinced me to not even look at your code.

Comment: thank you for your very valued opinion!

Comment: @gnasher729 that's probably a competitive programming template.

Comment: Since your code is working, you should post this question on CodeReview@StackExchange.com.  They are good at optimizing and performing code reviews.

Comment: Yep, I was writing the Facebook Hacker Cup 2015.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You properly pre-compute the primes over the desired range with the Sieve of Eratosthenes, which is good. However, what you want to know is the number of distinct prime factors of each number in your range, not whether it is prime or composite.

That calculation can also be done by sieving. Instead of keeping an array of booleans, keep an array of integers that count the number of distinct prime factors, and increment it for each prime factor found during sieving.

The sieving looks like this; we call the array *omega* because that is the name that number theorists give to the function that returns the number of distinct factors of a number:

```
omega := makeArray(2..limit, 0)

for i from 2 to limit
    if omega[i] == 0
        for j from i to limit step i
            omega[j] := omega[j] + 1
```

The first few elements of the *omega* array are 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2‌​, 2, 1, 3 ([A001221](http://oeis.org/A001221)).

Once you have *omega*, you can use it for all your queries:

```
function f(a, b, c)
    count := 0
    for k from a to b
         if omega[k] == c
             count := count + 1
    return count
```

For instance, `f(5,15,2) = 5` (the set 6, 10, 12, 14, 15), `f(2,10,1) = 7` (the set 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9), `f(24,42,3) = 2` (the set 30, 42), and `f(2,10000000,7) = 1716`.

If your range is too large to be conveniently sieved, you will have to factor each number in the range and count those with the correct number of distinct factors.

Answer (score 1):

your sieve function could possibly be optimised like this.

```
vector<int> siev(int max) {
    vector<int> ret;
    bool isPrime[max];

    for(int i=2; i<max; i++) isPrime[i]=true; // reset all bits

    for(int i=2; i<max; i++) {
        if(isPrime[i]) {
            ret.push_back(i);
            for(int j=i*i; j<max; j+=i) {
                isPrime[j]=false;
            }
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```